# Getting ImportError while import numpy on Anaconda Jupyter Notebook but numpy already installed. Any solution?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, importerror

[image: See Photos]

I ran same program before. But don't know suddenly it's showing ImportError. I did not change anything in Anaconda. Then what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a numpy import error, the C-libraries are not on the path. This means that you conda environment isn't activated.

To use conda environments in Jupyter follow this instuction:
[How to add your Conda environment to your jupyter notebook in just 4 steps](https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084)

On a side note: Why are you trying to mix *pip* and *conda* installs? This is asking for trouble!

Comment: yeah... I wanted to clarify the problem so. Anyway thanks.